# Error no mappedBy ao fazer relacionamento de 2 usuarios

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

eu tenho duas classes uma de usuario e outra de pedido, minha classe de usuario tem roles e na classe de pedido eu quero saber quem foi o funcionario e o cliente que fizeram o pedido e estou tendo este erro mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property.

Classe de usuario:

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    private String username;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @NotEmpty
    private String password;
    
    @Email
    private String email;
    
    private BigDecimal balance;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="TELEFONE")
    private Set<String> telefones = new HashSet<>();
    
    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name="ROLES")
    private Set<Integer> roles = new HashSet<>();
```

Classe de pedido

```
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;
   
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
   private User costumer;
   
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
   private User employer;
   
   private Payment payment;
   
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.order")
   private Set<ItemOrder> items = new HashSet<>();
   
   @JsonFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
   private LocalDateTime date;
```

Não faço ideia do que posso fazer pra arrumar isso, estou aprendendo e gostaria de saber como resolver.

Comment: Poderia descrever melhor a situação, seu mapeamento parece ter mais de um problema. Se for possível incluir um diagrama de classe

Answer (score 0):

O problema que você está ocorrendo é o seguinte:

Você mapeou o @OneToMany de forma errada.

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "costumer", insertable='false', updatable='false')
private List<Order> ordersCustomer = new ArrayList<>();

@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "employer", insertable='false', updatable='false')
private List<Order> ordersEmployer = new ArrayList<>();
```

Mapeando dessa forma significa que uma pessoa tem produtos vinculados tanto ao consumidor, quanto ao empregado.

insertable e updatable false significa que você não pode inserir objetos "Order" por meio de setters com a classe "User".

Outro erro é o seguinte:

```
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
   private User costumer;
   
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
   private User employer;
```

Pensa em termos de banco, qual o nome da coluna de cada um?

Talvez fique assim:

```
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "cod_costumer")
   private User costumer;
   
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "cod_employer")
   private User employer;
```

Sugiro ver a documentação do hibernate.
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html